# Kegerator Parts for Ball-lock kegs

Tags: corny-keg, kegerator

I know the difference between [ball-lock and pin-lock](http://www.installationpartssupply.com/mm5/images/corny_keg.jpg) kegs. My question arises in the fact my kegerator is set up for a [commercial](http://cdn.homebrewtalk.com/attachments/f35/33721d1316205730-using-commercial-keg-forumrunner_20110916_154202.jpg) keg and I need to convert it to fit my ball-lock keg.

[This is the Kegerator I have](http://www.beveragefactory.com/refrigerators/beer/danbyssteel-2.shtml?CAWELAID=1372131131&catargetid=1553582855&cagpspn=pla&gclid=COWnn-Lv9bUCFQ7znAodTnYA5Q)

Does anyone know the dimensions of the tubing/barbs/anything else I might need to hook up a standard CO2 tank to the ball-lock keg, then to a single tap draft tower?

*note - I do have the ball-lock connectors ([liquid out](http://www.cornykeg.com/autoThumb.asp?path=D%3a%5CWeb_Resorces%5Cproduct_images%5Ccatalog19985%5Cgray_ball_lock_connector.gif&iThumbSize=175) and [CO2 in](http://www.annapolishomebrew.com/content/images/thumbs/0002514_ball_lock_connector_in_w_mfl.jpeg))for the top of the keg.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking: the title mentions parts for pin lock kegs, but you mention in the first paragraph you have a ball lock keg, and that the kegerator is setup for a "commercial" keg - what is that?

Comment: Your second question, hooking up a CO2 tank to a draft tower, AFAIK you hook up the CO2 to the keg, and not the tower. But if you can provide more details about the tower, model/connections etc.. I'm sure someone will be able to help.

Comment: I hope the edits help clarify.

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be fairly simple to adapt to corny kegs (in fact there is a picture of the fridge filled with corny kegs.)

You have QDs for the kegs, so you have the connectors needed on the keg side. You also need hoses and connectors to connect the keg to the tower and to CO2:

- to beer in on the tower: push 6-10' of 3/16" beer line over the barbed beer out QD on the keg and clamp with a hose clamp. To connect the hose to the tower, use beer line connectors, like [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002EAJXW).  (You probably already have these on your existing beer out line.)

[image: beer line connectors]

- CO2 from the tank. You connect the keg to the tank with 1/4" or 5/16" gas hose slipped over the gray gas QD and clamped. The regulator output is also barbed so you do the same with that - slip over the hose and clamp down.

And that's it!

If you have already the parts for the sanke (commercial) keg, but have no plans to use them, then you already have all the parts you need. You can then just cut off the keg coupler at the hose, and fix this to your beer QD, and do the same for the gas line.

Comment: Since I have never put anything together that is supposed to hold pressure (like the CO2 hose/connector) or hold liquid (keg to tap), do you have any insight into precautions that should be taken to prevent leaks, blowing lines, etc.?

Comment: Both the beer and gas lines should be rated for at least 60 psi. Use hose clamps on the barbs, to stop the hose from being blown off.